# How to retain the values stored in reference variables of a given service instance in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am implementing a clipboard in my application. In my service, I have two methods, `copy` and `paste`. `copy()` takes in the source folder and the source item as the arguments while `paste()` takes in the destination folder as argument. 
In my copy method, I save the values of the arguments in the service level private variables and use them later in my paste method.

As soon as I hit `Ctrl + C`, I invoke the copy method with the parameters and then when I hit `Ctrl + V`, I invoke the paste method with the destination folder.

When, my destination folder is same as my source folder, my logic is working correctly and the values which I stored in the reference still exists on the instance variable of Clipboard Service. But, when my destination folder is different, the variables are undefined in the service.

I think I am missing some minute detail here in my implementation. Could anyone help me out if I am approaching it correctly and what's the solution to this problem?

Here is my code:

```
export class ClipService {
    private srcFolder;
    private srcItem;

    constructor() {
    }

    copy(srcFolder, srcItem) {
        this.srcFolder = srcFolder;
        this.srcItem = srcItem;
    }

    paste(destFolder) {

    }

}
```

In an another class, I import this class, create a new instance of it in the constructor and then, invoke it as follows:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'new-comp',
 templateUrl: 'new-comp.html'
})
export class NewComp {

private clipboard: ClipService;

constructor(){
 this.clipboard = new ClipService();
}

private keydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        if (event.defaultPrevented) return;
        let folder = this.folder.json;
        let item = folder.activeItem;
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 67) {
            this.clipboard.copy(folder, item);
        } else if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 86) {
             this.clipboard.paste(this.finder.activeFolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use angular services like that. You should use dependency injection in order to use them.

The solution to your problem is:

```
constructor(private clipboard: ClipService){}
```

Your way, every time that you are instantiating a component, you are creating a different service. This way, the angular DI system, gives you a reference to the *same* instance of the service, which is instantiated and managed by the Angular framework.

[Check out this stackblitz for an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bq6lmd)

TL;DR:

Services are singletons in the OOP lingo, instances of a class that should only be instantiated once. If you try to instantiate more than one, you're doing something not expected by the singleton. Singletons, are like global variables: a way to share state across a program. In order to make it easy to manage instantiation of singletons without errors, DI (dependency injection) mechanisms/frameworks exist. One such framework exists in angular, and automatically instantiates a singleton service when needed, and makes sure to share that instance with every component (or instance of a component) that needs access to that service.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. It worked like a charm. :) I will definitely keep a note of this :)

Comment: @Donut I've updated with an example to clarify it a bit. Check out the [part about services in the tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4). You can read more about DI [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#inject-a-service) you pretty much only need this part of the page. If you need help, ask! :)